# How to test non-exported Typescript modules?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, npm, babel-jest

The compiler accepts my current solution, so nothing is marked red, but the tests still fail: "ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined".

I would like to test the following module in TypeScript:
File1.ts:

```
module MyModule {
  export function myFunction(): string {
    return "Hello, World!";
  }
}
```

This is how the test currently looks:
File1.test.ts:

```
module MyModule {
  describe('Test1', () => {
    test('equal', () => {
      expect(myFunction()).toBe("Hello, World!");
    });
  });
}
```

Both files are specified in the tsconfig.json:

```
"files":[
  "File1.test.ts",
  "File1.ts"
]
```

I would be very grateful for any advice and help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to import and export your module. Test this one:

In your File1.ts:

```
export module MyModule {
  export function myFunction(): string {
    return "Hello, World!";
  }
}
```

And in your File1.test.ts:

```
import { MyModule } from './File1';

describe('Test1', () => {
  test('equal', () => {
    expect(MyModule.myFunction()).toBe("Hello, World!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Sure, that's how it works. But I want to keep the structure in my File1.ts. I don't use a modern module system ("module"="none"). The compiler already accepts the solution, but I suspect that the test framework does not know all files. I just don't know now how to teach jest-babel where the files are.